# new Date(2015,2,30) and new Date('2015-2-30')

Tags: javascript, date

Both the above new date formats give different results.

```
new Date(2015,2,30) : Date 2015-03-29T18:30:00.000Z

new Date('2015-2-30') : Invalid Date
```

Why is this different ?

EDITS
Points  : 
1. Month index in the first format start with 0.
2. The first format handles the overflow of the dates and hence is not a prefered way to test for invalid dates.

For eg : `new Date(2015, 1, 30) {when the user is looking for 30,Feb,2015}` will be converted to 01,March,2015. That is the extra date is carry forwarded to the month. Pretty indecent a convert according to me. However, if you write `new Date("2015-2-30"){when the user is looking for 30,Feb,2015}` , this will be an invalid date.

Comment: Please name the standard that defines the `YYYY-M-D` date format.

Comment: First calls a constructor with 3 paramter, second with on parameter

Comment: Not to mention that there's no February 30th…

Comment: @deceze : Right ,... i want to test for invalid date... so the command is just fine.

Comment: So then it would help if you'd clarify a bit how you expect this to work and what you're surprised about. It's different because, well, *it's different*. Are you surprised that the first one yields a valid date, or that the second one *doesn't* yield a valid date?

Comment: @deceze Sure the difference i was looking for was the way tiemzones and overflow of dates is handled. When we have the dateString being sent ... the overflows are not handled and it is an invalid date .. This is not the case when we send the year, month etc.. Also a point to be noted was that months start with 0.

Comment: That's the only real point to be noted… `2015-02-30` (even with the fixed format) is an invalid date; `2015`, `2`, `30` is a *valid* date, because March 30th exists. So, 1) you have perhaps surprising behaviour regarding months being 0-indexed, and 2) you have a bug in your date format. Which of these you're most surprised about is unclear from your question alone.

Comment: @deceze 2015, 2, 30 is a valid date, because March 30th exists >> Correct .. but 2015, 1, 30 is a valid date too ... which is incorrect right ... new date converts 2015, 1, 30 to 01,March when the user was looking for 30,February (Invalid date in essence).This is the surprise element.  However this overflow of dates is handled if i say new Date('2015-02-30').

Comment: @deceze : thanks for helping me identify what was surprising me actually ..  :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The output will be

```
console.log(new Date(2015,2,30)); // here 2 represents the march, ,month starts from 0 where 0 represents first month
console.log(new Date('2015-3-30'));

Mon Mar 30 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
Mon Mar 30 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)


new Date('2015-2-30') // it means 30th day in February; which will convert it to second march
```

Comment: new Date(2015,01,29) : Invalid date.

Comment: You don't have 29 in feb 2015, so it ll be converted to March 01st. check in browser console, it ll return the date string.

Comment: You should not do `new Date('2015-3-30')` ever as there are any of 3 possible outcomes, and Safari, Firefox and Chrome all give a different result (and all are consistent with ECMA-262).

Comment: @RobG I'm not suggesting him to use, I'm just explaining what will be the output if it is used.

Answer (score 2):

You're calling the [Date constructor](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf#sec-date-constructor.a4) with different types of parameters :

- in the first case you're providing integers which it uses to populate its fields (the first three being the year, the month and the day of the month) ; note that the monthes are 0-indexed : a value of 1 in that field will correspond to February rather than January
- in the second case you're providing a `String` which will be parsed as if passed to `Date.parse`, that is as an ISO 8601 Extended Format date (`YYYY‐MM‐DDTHH:mm:ss.sssZ`)

Comment: It doesn't work only with ISO-8601. There is some more inputs available. Please look at my answer.

Comment: There is only one Date constructor.

Comment: @RobG alright, even if I don't see the point ECMA-262 does specify that "The Date constructor is a single function whose behaviour is overloaded based upon the number and types of its arguments". I don't see a way to put that into my answer without making it over complicated though, feel free to edit if you're more inspired.

Comment: @Aaron—answers should be complete and accurate. It's fine to (accurately) paraphrase the specification and include a link to it. You could just say that the Date constructor behaves differently depending on the number and type of the arguments passed to it, then continue with your explanation. Also, the built-in parser is only required to parse ISO 80601 extended format date strings, RFC 2822 is not mentioned.

Comment: @RobG I was lazy, thanks for insisting and providing additional info ! I updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

[Check docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date).

It's because by first example you pass arguments

```
new Date(year, month[, day[, hour[, minutes[, seconds[, milliseconds]]]]]);
```

And by second one you pass date string that is not valid. Missing `0` before `2`

```
new Date(dateString);
```

Comment: What is "valid"? Implementations are free to apply any heuristics they like to a format that is not strictly consistent with ISO 8601, even say 2016/23/45.

Answer (score 1):

You can create new `Date` in these ways:

```
var d = new Date();
var d = new Date(milliseconds);
var d = new Date(dateString);
var d = new Date(year, month, day, hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds);
```

For `dateString` it must be provided by one of these input:

```
ISO Date    "2015-03-25" (The International Standard)
Short Date  "03/25/2015" or "2015/03/25"
Long Date   "Mar 25 2015" or "25 Mar 2015"
Full Date   "Wednesday March 25 2015"
```

Comment: "Must"? Only one of those formats is consistent with the format in ECMAScript specifications after ed 3, any or all of the others might result in an invalid date. Or not. See [*Date.parse*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-date.parse), which uses the same parsing algorithm as that used for the Date constructor, which need not be consistent across implementations. And you can also do `new Date(dateInstance)`. ;-)

Comment: A *dateInstance* is an instance created by the Date constructor, it is not a *dateString*, which is a string. I have read it again. You provide four examples of creating a new Date, I provided a fifth. Only one of the parsing examples you provide is required to be correctly parsed by the Date parser, the other three are implementation dependent, so "must" should not be used. There are many other formats that are parsed by some Date implementations, and not all the formats you suggest are parsed by current implementations.

Answer (score 0):

There is a fundamental rule with ECMAScript dates: never use the Date constructor or Date.parse (they are equivalent for parsing) to parse strings.

Given `new Date(2015,2,30)` the values are treated as "local" for 30 March 2015, so the UTC time value is adjusted for the timezone offset on the host machine for that date. The outcome will be identical in all implementations consistent with all versions of ECMAScript from ed 3 onward at least.

Given the string `new Date('2015-3-30')`, the browser parsing algorithm is used. That string it might be treated as:

1. An invalid date, which is the result in Safari since it's ISO–like but not the correct format and the day is invalid for February
2. ISO 8601 and hence **UTC** for 30 March 2015, which is the result in Firefox and is also consistent with the standard since it's not valid ISO 8601 and hence can be parsed any way the implementation wishes to
3. A **local** date for 30 March 2015 which is the result in Chrome.

Also, given `new Date('2015-2-30')`:

1. Safari and Firefox give an invalid date
2. Chrome gives 2 March 2015 as a local date (i.e. 30 February rolls over to 2 March, which is the same behaviour as `new Date(2015,1,30)`)

All the above outcomes are consistent with ECMAScript 2016. Hence the opening statement.

#### Edit

The quickest way to validate the values of a date while parsing is to test the month, in the simplest case of parsing a date in d/m/y format:

```js
function parseDMY(s) {
  var b = s.split(/\D/);
  var d = new Date(b[2], --b[1], b[0]);
  // If month is wrong, return invalid date
  return d && d.getMonth() == b[1]? d : new Date(NaN);
}

// Dates in d/m/y format
['23/10/2015','32/10/2015','12/13/2015'].forEach(function(s){
  var d = parseDMY(s);
  console.log(s + ' : ' + (isNaN(d)? 'Invalid' : 'Valid'));
});
```

Comment: how do we check for invalid date in the shortest possible way ?

Comment: @BhumiSinghal—where parsing a date only string, just check that the month is correct, since if either the day or month numbers are out of bounds, the value returned by *getMonth* will not be consistent with the month provided. The year can't be out of bounds.